# Positioning accelerometer on a cantilever beam

Tags: measurements, vibration

What is the appropriate position to place an accelerometer, along the length of a cantilever beam, for the follwing two cases:

1. The beam is under sinusoidal excitation at the free end.
2. The beam experience an impact load at the free end.

Comment: what are you trying to measure?

Comment: I am interested getting the natural frequency from the accelerometer data.

Comment: A cantilever beam has several "modes" each with its own natural frequency. Which one are you interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases it would be best to place the accelerometer as far as possible from the fixed point.

However IMHO, for an adequate approximation of the natural frequency (assuming the damping is not critical) you'd only need to use the second part of the measurement (impact). The first part (forced sinusoidal excitation) will only convey information on the transient response, or through the shift of the phase.

Answer (score 0):

Put it at the free end.  What I would do here is called a "bump test" it is when you measure the response frequency after an impact using a data collector.  I agree with Nmech.  You could just hit it and measure the response to get the natural frequency.
You can get the natural frequency from anywhere on the beam in reality, but the amplitudes will likely be largest on the free end.